# Coloring the background of cells in a table when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to do the following:
Create a 4x4 table (16 squares), each table cell (square) that receives a click of the mouse should change its color background to green and receive the value "1" in a variable (do not intend to show the number "1" in the labeled cells, but only record this value in a variable in order to make the sum of how many cells were colored).

Thanks all!

Comment: share what you have done

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We're here to help you solve problems with what you have. We're not here to do it for you. Please show us what you've got so far

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not here to do the work for you

Comment: All of you who answered are only encouraging people like this to continue doing what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count;

$('td').on('click',function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#cccccc');
    count++;
});
```

count should have the number of cells clicked and the background color will change as well. Am assuming using jQuery is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

HTML :

```
<table id="clickable-table">
<tr class="row">
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="column"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="column"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="column"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="column"></td>
    <td class="column"></td>
</tr>
```

JS/jQuery:-

```
var count = 0;
$(".column").off("click").on("click",function(){
   $(this).css("background-color","green");
   count++;
   console.log(count);
});
```

CSS :

```
td.column {
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   border: solid 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
    <table width="50%">
<tbody><tr>
  <td id="cell1" class="tblCell none">1</td>
  <td id="cell2" class="tblCell none">2</td>
  <td id="cell3" class="tblCell none">3</td>
  <td id="cell4" class="tblCell none">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="cell5" class="tblCell none">5</td>
  <td id="cell6" class="tblCell none">6</td>
  <td id="cell7" class="tblCell none">7</td>
  <td id="cell8" class="tblCell none">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="cell9" class="tblCell none">9</td>
  <td id="cell10" class="tblCell none">10</td>
  <td id="cell11" class="tblCell none">11</td>
  <td id="cell12" class="tblCell none">12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="cell13" class="tblCell none">13</td>
  <td id="cell14" class="tblCell none">14</td>
  <td id="cell15" class="tblCell none">15</td>
  <td id="cell16" class="tblCell none">16</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
    .none{
  background-color: #F3F5F6
}

.green{
  background-color: green
}
```

Javascript Code

```
    var count = 0;
$(".tblCell").click(function(){ 

    if($("#"+this.id).hasClass("none")){
    $("#"+this.id).addClass("green")
    $("#"+this.id).removeClass("none")
    count++;
  }
  else if($("#"+this.id).hasClass("green")) {
    $("#"+this.id).addClass("none")
    $("#"+this.id).removeClass("green")
    count--;
  }
console.log("Count Is : " + count);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works well. , and help you

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        td {
            border: 2px solid #000;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        </table>
        <p id="x"></p>
        <script>
            var x = document.getElementById("x");
            var counter = 0;
            window.onclick = function(){clk(event);}
            function clk(event){
                var againClk = event.target.style.backgroundColor; 
                if(event.target.nodeName == "TD" && againClk != "green" ){
                    event.target.style.backgroundColor ="green";
                    x.innerHTML = "counter : " + (++counter);
                }

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```